# Django Form Doesn't Save to Table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Here is the issue - when the user presses the 'Save' button, the settings they entered SHOULD be saved to the table. However, this doesn't happen. After you are redirected, you can check the 'Settings' page again or the admin site and the changes will not appear. I even put in several print statements which ALL run, but I can't figure out why this is happening. Here is the code (I only included what is necessary)

**views.py**

```
class SettingsView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
template_name = 'example/settings.html'
form_class = ExampleSettingsForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('example:index')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(SettingsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['page'] = 'settings'
    return context

def get_initial(self):
    initial = super(SettingsView, self).get_initial()

    initial['example1'] = self.request.user.example.example1
    initial['example2'] = self.request.user.example.example2
    initial['example3'] = self.request.user.example.example3
    initial['example4'] = self.request.user.example.example4
    initial['example5'] = self.request.user.example.example5
    initial['example6'] = self.request.user.example.example6
    initial['example7'] = self.request.user.example.example7

    return initial

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save_to_example(self.request.user)
    print("Form valid.")
    return super(SettingsView, self).form_valid(form)

@method_decorator(shelter_login_required)
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(SettingsView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ExampleSettingsForm(forms.Form):
example1 = forms.CharField()

example2 = forms.TimeField()
example3 = forms.TimeField()

example4 = AddressField()

example5 = forms.IntegerField()

example6 = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$')

example7 = forms.BooleanField()

def save_to_example(self, user):
    user.example.example1 = self.cleaned_data['example1']
    user.example.example2 = self.cleaned_data['example2']
    user.example.example3 = self.cleaned_data['example3']
    user.example.example4 = self.cleaned_data['example4']
    user.example.example5 = self.cleaned_data['example5']
    user.example.example6 = self.cleaned_data['example6']
    user.example.example7 = self.cleaned_data['example7']
    user.save()
    print(user.example.example1)
```

**models.py**

```
class Example(models.Model):
    example1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    example2 = models.TimeField(null=True)
    example3 = models.TimeField(null=True)

    example_male = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    example_female = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    example6 = models.IntegerField(default=10)

    example5 = AddressField(null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    example7 = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    example_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    example_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_example(sender, instance, created, **kwarg):
    if created:
        Example.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_example(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not instance.is_superuser:
        instance.example.save()
```

**Note -** I know the indentation isn't correct. I had trouble copy/pasting into Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't see any model to be save to. How is user defined?

Comment: @Vasko There is a model. I just didn't include it in the answer because it is kind of long and I don't think it has anything to do with the model not saving. I might update my answer in a bit with the models.py file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def save_to_example(self, user):
    example = user.example
    example.example1 = self.cleaned_data['example1']
    example.example2 = self.cleaned_data['example2']
    example.example3 = self.cleaned_data['example3']
    example.example4 = self.cleaned_data['example4']
    example.example5 = self.cleaned_data['example5']
    example.example6 = self.cleaned_data['example6']
    example.example7 = self.cleaned_data['example7']
    example.save()
    print(example.example1)
```

Comment: No luck. It certainly made things shorter, but the problem hasn't gone away.

Comment: What type of example is? Could you provide additional info about example? It seems example is related objects to user.

Comment: I have added the models.py file to my question.

Comment: save_to_example has different fields compared to Example model if it matters. And save method is called on user but should be on example object.